# CurrencyConvert work not perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wkhtmltopdf

```
function numberToCurrency(amount) {

            var wholeDigits;
            var thousandsSeparator = "."
            var centSeparator = ","
            var currencyNum = "";

            if(amount.indexOf(".") != -1) {
                var hasCents = true;
            } else {
                var hasCents = false;
            }

            if (hasCents == true) {
                var num = amount.split(".");
                var wholeDigits = num[0].split("");
                var centAmount = num[1];
                var centDigits = num[1].split("");

                if (centDigits.length == 0) {
                    centDigits += "0";
                }
                if ((centDigits.length > 0) && (centDigits.length < 2)) {
                    centDigits += "0";
                }

            } else {
                centDigits = "";
                centSeparator = "";
                wholeDigits = amount.split("");
            }

            var countDigits = wholeDigits.length;

            var revDigits = wholeDigits.reverse();

            for(var i=0; i<countDigits; i++) {
                    if ((i%3 == 0) && (i !=0)) {
                        currencyNum += thousandsSeparator+revDigits[i];
                    } else {
                        currencyNum += wholeDigits[i];
                    }
            };

            var revCurrency = currencyNum.split("").reverse().join("");

            var finalCurrency = revCurrency+centSeparator+centAmount+"  €";

            return finalCurrency;
        }
```

I've problems with this convert..

**How I become the values?**

I become the values from SQL.., for example {{AMOUNT1}} is in a SQL table the row "amount1" the value for this is: 1839936,59

`select AMOUNT1,* from INVOICE where INVOICENR = '123456'`

Then I use the DOM in HTML with this code:

```
<input id="AMOUNT1" type="text" title="1.839.936,59" initval="1839936,59" value="1839936,59" name="BETRAGNETTO" style="text-align:right;width:calc(100% - 18px) !important;" decimalplaces="2" numval="1839936.59">
```

that i use for all placeholders for a wkhtmltopdf template..
in the .tmpl i write this so:

```
<td class="tr1 td2"><p class="p2 ft4"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(numberToCurrency('{{AMOUNT1}}'))</script></P></TD>
```

**OUTPUT (in a .pdf) - *the italic font = SQ*L**

1. {{AMOUNT1}}: 1.839.936,59 € *(in SQL: 1839636,59)*
2. {{AMOUNT2}}: 55.198,1 €   *(in SQL: 55198,10)*            <--- decimal places?
3. {{AMOUNT3}}: 0,0 €    *(in SQL: 0,00)*                <--- same here
4. {{AMOUNT4}}: 15.733,979999999996 €   *(in SQL: 15733,97)* <--- what is this?

All the amounts are different, but in sql all the same, like xxxxx,xx.

what is wrong with the script?

Comment: Swearing on SO is ***not acceptable***. I've edited your question to remove the swearing. Please refrain in future.

Comment: Not understanding what you mean by all amounts are different, but in SQL they are all the same...

Comment: i'm confused why there are commas where the periods belong and visa versa...

Comment: The script convert not correctly, all the same XXXXXXX,XX, some convert in XXXXXX,X (not in XXXXXX,XX) some in X,X (not in X,XX) and the other in XXXXX,XXXXXXX (not in XXXXX,XX)

Comment: @abc123: Different cultures use different characters for decimal and thousands separation (sadly). In several, `,` is the decimal point, and `.` is a thousands separator. Some use a space as a thousands separator (and that's not confusing *at all*)... :-)